# Compiz window decoration for Budgie Desktop

Tags: 16.04, compiz, window-manager, budgie

So i just loaded Budgie Ubuntu Remix or whatever its called and installed Compiz. Did the `compiz --replace` in startup apps workaround to get compiz on statup but some windows like terminal use `gtk-window-decoration` instead of Budgie's. Programs like the File explorer still use budgie's window decoration/theme but not all apps. I tried changing the window decoration manager to `/usr/bin/budgie-wm` but that didnt work. How can i get this working?

I also have another issue when i use compiz is that the budgie shutdown buttons dont work. I have to logout, shutdown or reboot from the command line.

Has anyone fixed this or has had this issue too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So don't use compiz?

Comment: not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to change the decoration manager, but you can change the gtk theme for the window decoration until it fits (use the dconf-editor).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)